# Scale image to fit inside imageview with xamarin glide library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-glide

I'm having trouble getting images from certain sources to load in my recycler view. Inside my view for the rows is this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Most images seem to load fine here, but when I load an image from the user's device from uri it seems to not show up in this view. I did notice that if I change the height to something larger the image does show. Here is how I'm loading the image inside my recycler view adapater.

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(_recipes[position].ImageUrl);
            Glide.With(_context)
                .Load(uri)
                .DontAnimate()
                .Into(vh.RecipeImage);
```

When the image doesn't show its just blank. Is this something wrong with scaling? How do I get the image to fit properly?

Comment: have you set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the `ImageView`.

Comment: Please post your code that display image in `RecyclerView` .